# Is there a way to match Regular Expression parameters without caring what order they are in?

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to convert a search query like this:

```
bridge AND (car OR boat)
```

Into a regex that would match against this:

```
My car goes over bridge.
```

I am close to getting it (I think), this is what I have so far:

```
.*(bridge).*(car|boat)
```

That doesn't work though, but this does:

```
.*(car|boat).*(bridge)
```

My regex seems to be dependent on the order of the words in the string. Is there a way to match parameters without caring what order they are in?

Comment: Can you apply two expressions in sequence? In this case it won't be order dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookahead assertions `(?= ... )` to accomplish this. Such assertions would overcome the burden of permutations when dealing with alternation ( | ).

For example:

```
^(?=.*?\bbridge\b)(?=.*?\b(car|boat)\b)
```

Since assertions are "zero-width", in this example once either assertion is evaluated you are still at the beginning of the string. Effectively this pattern says "match the beginning of the string", and "make sure that both "bridge" and either "car or boat" are found at some point after the beginning of the string.

Each assertion would correspond to the AND part of your query; the OR would be handled by the alternation. This could change when your query changes, but holds for your example.

Comment: This looks great, but can I get around having word boundaries by removing the \b, or would that not work as desired? like this: ^(?=.*?bridge)(?=.*?(car|boat))

Comment: Also, how would I say car NOT boat (where it should contain car, but not boat)?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the word boundaries; I just thought you would need them. Without the boundaries you will match things like "drawbridge" or "carport" or "showboat".

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead for the NOT portion. e.g.  `^(?=.*?car)(?!.*boat)`

Comment: NP. Keep in mind that (in .NET at least) any regex pattern can go inside of a lookaround assertion--even another lookaround assertion. This is quite powerful, but does add a degree of complexity to your patterns. Also keep in mind the whole concept of "zero width" when crafting your lookarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, not in a single a regular expression. A regexp is for matching an *ordered* sequence of characters.

You *could* generate a pattern that explicitly allowed for both orderings, of course. I.e. if you want to match A or B in any order, you'd generate something like: `(?:.*A.*B)|(?:.*B.*A)`. But to cover all permutations would yield a rather huge regexp if the number of terms grows.

A better solution is probably to match each term with a separate regular expression and combine matches yourself, e.g. by implementing a simple boolean expression tree.